# Twilio <Gather> Speech Recognition support in twilio python package

Tags: python, twilio

Need some help in Twilio. Twilio **Gather** verb supports `input="speech"` which recognizes speech as mentioned in their site. Does the Twilio python package support this speech recognition yet? Couldn't find any help documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It seems that the latest Python package only implemented partial support for `input="speech"` and the related TwiML attributes which makes it unusable at the moment.

I am raising a bug internally and will get this fixed as soon as possible. I will notify you here when it is ready.

Comment: Good news already, this has been fixed in a PR: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/pull/348